# Defining manifolds with ring structure

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Manifolds are locally Euclidean by definition. This can be identified as a complex manifold if the dimension of the manifold is even.

My question is can we define manifolds with a local ring structure? Also, can we define smooth manifolds and define tangent spaces being modules, etc?

Thanks

Comment: "This can be identified as a complex manifold if the dimension of the manifold is even." This is false. Every complex manifold is an even-dimensional smooth manifold, but not every even-dimensional smooth manifold admits a complex structure, e.g. $S^4$.

Comment: Yes, but it's basically the theory of finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebras: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924160/is-there-a-theory-of-lie-rings