# Are there "lie fields" other than $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$?

Tags: field-theory, smooth-manifolds, topological-rings

In $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ with their usual smooth manifold structure, addition, multiplication and divisions by a non-zero element are all smooth functions. Are there other fields along with a non-$0$-dimensional smooth manifold structure in their underlying set satisfying this?

Comment: Yes, but perhaps for unsatisfying reasons. E.g. you can get a finite field with the discrete topology as $0$-dimensional "Lie field". If you assume connectedness, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are the only "Lie fields".

Comment: @Thorgott What if we just assume non-$0$-dimensionality but not connectedness?

Comment: If one allows infinite dimensional Lie groups, wouldn't $\Bbb R(X)$ be a good candidate?

Comment: Connectedness is automatic (if the dimension is greater than $0$) since the connected component of $0$ is an ideal, and a field has no nontrivial proper ideals.

Comment: @EricWofsey i guess that insight makes this question a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/924533/1083256

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You're right, obviously not a Banach manifold